# whats the meaning of "scant" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

http://infertility.about.com/od/tryingtoconceive101/a/cervicalmucus.htm

The Writer in the above article talks about the observation of cervical mucus.(for more, look into the fourth point, under subtitle *How to Check Your Cervical Mucus*.)

He notes as follows

> If what you find seems sticky, or findings are **scant**, you're probably not ovulating yet.

Does *scant* means *if cervical mucus is less sticky* or if the amount of cervical mucus you took from your vagina ( using a finger) are less ?

Comment: *Scant* means "very little". Ref.: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/scant

Answer (score 2):

> Does scant means if cervical mucus is less sticky or if the amount of cervical mucus you took from your vagina ( using a finger) are less ?

It means *minimal*, *barely detectable*, or *falling short of some required amount*. That is, "[if you don't have much cervical mucus], you're probably not ovulating".